# How to display second level menu on another node page

Tags: views, routes, taxonomy-terms

I created a menu by Menu block module. I added a link 'to /news' in the first level. The second level are news categories (taxonomy items). I want to display the categories (2 level) on node page. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Taxonomy Menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) Module. It creates you a menu item for each term which you then can place in your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [menu_block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block)
It allows you to have different levels of your menu in different blocks.
Just create a menu-block for your main navigation(only level 1) and a second for level 2 only. Set the second menu-block only to show up on `node*` or what ever you need.